# Saving combo box on exit

Tags: c#, combobox

I am adding item to a combo box programatically via Items.Add() method of the combo box. The item is added to the combo box, but it is not there after the user exits the application.  I followed the advice given here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvcs/thread/760fc26d-dc45-4827-aab6-21eebff07333

But ran into the same issue as the OP, namely, there was no defintion for "Items" Foreach (string Item in ComboItems.Items)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I took off the "Items" and changed it to ComboItems, and added Properties.Setting.Default.Save(), after the foreach, but now the form doesn't close.  The debugger shows that control has passed to the form and it's waiting for user input.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to save The Combox items if the user exits your application if you use that **Comboboc.Items.Add** in Runtime.

The only way is that you may need to have Storage(Database) and store those items in it.
After that bind it to your combobox.

E.G:

```
private void SaveItemtoCombobox()
{

  //save method stuff

}


private void LoadDatatoCombobox()
{


   cmbBox1.DataSource = source;
   cmbBox1.DisplayMember = "MyTableName";

}
```

Regards